# Convert rows to columns in mysql V2

Tags: mysql, sql, row

In reference to this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985340/convert-rows-to-columns-in-mysql

I have this code where it kind of joins two tables with diff colum names, I thought I could do this so that I can use bluefeet's code, cause I have separate tables wherein the string location is on table_1 and the location id is on table_2. it looks like this

table_1:

```
id | location
1  | East Flow
2  | East Level
3  | East Pressure
4  | East MR
5  | West Flow
6  | West Level
7  | West Pressure
8  | West MR
```

table 2:

```
locationid | val
   1       | 10
   2       | 20
   3       | 30
   4       | 40
   5       | 100
   6       | 200
   7       | 300
   8       | 400
```

so when you execute this query it will look something like this:

```
SELECT id, locationid, location, val 
FROM table_1, table_2
WHERE id = locationid 
GROUP BY id
```

output:

```
id   | locationid |     location    | val
1    |     1      |   East Flow     | 10
2    |     2      |   East Level    | 20
3    |     3      |   East Pressure | 30
4    |     4      |   East MR       | 40
5    |     5      |   West Flow     | 100
6    |     6      |   West Level    | 200
7    |     7      |   West Pressure | 300
8    |     8      |   West MR       | 400
```

---

I want to merge @bluefeet's code to my code so that I can use her code, cause her code already works:

```
select 
  substring_index(location, ' ', 1) Location,
  max(case when location like '%Flow' then val end) Flow,
  max(case when location like '%Level' then val end) Level,
  max(case when location like '%Pressure' then val end) Pressure,
  max(case when location like '%MR' then val end) MR
from yourtable
group by substring_index(location, ' ', 1)
```

How do I merge that? Select within a select or something?
This is how I was hoping the output would look like:

From this:

```
  Location    | Val |
East Flow     | 10  |
East Level    | 20  |
East Pressure | 30  |
East MR       | 40  |
West Flow     | 100 |
West Level    | 200 |
West Pressure | 300 |
West MR       | 400 |
```

To this:

```
Location | Flow| Level | Pressure |  MR   |
East     | 10  |  20   |    300   |  400  |
West     | 100 |  200  |    300   |  400  |
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just JOIN your tables to get the result:

```
select 
  substring_index(t1.location, ' ', 1) Location,
  max(case when t1.location like '%Flow' then t2.val end) Flow,
  max(case when t1.location like '%Level' then t2.val end) Level,
  max(case when t1.location like '%Pressure' then t2.val end) Pressure,
  max(case when t1.location like '%MR' then t2.val end) MR
from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.locationid
group by substring_index(t1.location, ' ', 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bf80/1)

Comment: I'm having problems with the output, it works - kind of. can i use the locationid instead? sorry i'm just following orders

Comment: What do you mean locationid instead?  You have 8 different location ids how are you going to determine which id goes into each column?

Comment: Are you going to know the locationIds ahead of time?

Comment: @hearmeroar this would be a horrible way to do this - but try this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bf80/9

Comment: What if we forget about the table 1 and just on table 2 just use the locationid on that?

Comment: oh got it, i used your code but modified it and removed the inner joins. i see why you said this is a horrible way.

Comment: does `MAX` gets the latest value or does it just gets the largest value?

Comment: it gets the largest value

Comment: can you check out my post on getting the latest value? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013335/get-the-latest-value-in-mysql?